# compiling numpy with sunperf atlas libraries

Tags: python, numpy, compilation, scipy, sunstudio

I would like to use the sunperf libraries when compiling scipy and numpy. I tried using setupscons.py which seems to check from SUNPERF libraries, but it didnt recognize where mine are: here is a listing of /pkg/linux/SS12/sunstudio12.1 (thats where the sunperf library lives):

```
wkerzend@mosura:/home/wkerzend>ls /pkg/linux/SS12/sunstudio12.1/lib/
CCios/            libdbx_agent.so@    libsunperf.so.3@
amd64/            libfcollector.so@   libtha.so@
collector.jar@        libfsu.so@        libtha.so.1@
dbxrc@            libfsu.so.1@        locale/
debugging.so@        libfui.so@        make.rules@
er.rc@            libfui.so.1@        rw7/
libblacs_openmpi.so@    librtc.so@        sse2/
libblacs_openmpi.so.1@    libscalapack.so@    stlport4/
libcollectorAPI.so@    libscalapack.so.1@  svr4.make.rules@
libcollectorAPI.so.1@    libsunperf.so@        tools_svc_mgr@
```

---

I tried to specify this directory in sites.cfg, but I still get the following errors:

```
Checking if g77 needs dummy main - MAIN__.
Checking g77 name mangling - '_', '', lower-case.
Checking g77 C compatibility runtime ...-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6 -            L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-    linux/3.4.6/../../../../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../.. -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -lfrtbegin -lg2c -lm
Checking MKL ... Failed (could not check header(s) : check config.log in build/scons/scipy/integrate for more details)
Checking ATLAS ... Failed (could not check header(s) : check config.log in build/scons/scipy/integrate for more details)
Checking SUNPERF ... Failed (could not check symbol cblas_sgemm : check config.log in build/scons/scipy/integrate for more details))
Checking Generic BLAS ... yes
Checking for BLAS (Generic BLAS) ... Failed: BLAS (Generic BLAS) test could not be linked and run
Exception: Could not find F77 BLAS, needed for integrate package:
  File "/priv/manana1/wkerzend/install_dir/scipy-0.7.1/scipy/integrate/SConstruct", line 2:
GetInitEnvironment(ARGUMENTS).DistutilsSConscript('SConscript')
  File "/home/wkerzend/python_coala/numscons-0.10.1-py2.6.egg/numscons/core/numpyenv.py", line 108:
build_dir = '$build_dir', src_dir = '$src_dir')
  File "/priv/manana1/wkerzend/python_coala/numscons-0.10.1-py2.6.egg/numscons/scons-local/scons-local-1.2.0/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 549:
    return apply(_SConscript, [self.fs,] + files, subst_kw)
  File "/priv/manana1/wkerzend/python_coala/numscons-0.10.1-py2.6.egg/numscons/scons-local/scons-local-1.2.0/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 259:
exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "/priv/manana1/wkerzend/install_dir/scipy-0.7.1/build/scons/scipy/integrate/SConscript", line 15:
    raise Exception("Could not find F77 BLAS, needed for integrate package")
error: Error while executing scons command. See above for more information.

If you think it is a problem in numscons, you can also try executing the scons
command with --log-level option for more detailed output of what numscons is
doing, for example --log-level=0; the lowest the level is, the more detailed
the output it.-----
```

---

any help is appreciated

```
Wolfgang
```

Comment: Any progress with this? I'm also trying to get numpy/scipy up and running in this environment. I've managed to compile both numpy and scipy in a local install but without atlas. Also not all tests pass. I realize this isn't a very useful post but I can post links if it will be helpful.

Comment: I should also mention that I'm trying this with python3.

Comment: Should be linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311869/python-numpy-on-solaris-blas-slow-or-not-linked

Comment: Please share your `site.cfg` file too.