# python numpy on solaris, blas slow or not linked?

Tags: python, numpy

Matrix-Matrix multiplies are very slow on my Solaris install (running on a sparc server) compared to my OSX install (on a laptop!). The laptop runs 100 times faster (for matrix-matrix multiplies of 3000x3000 dense random matrices of doubles).

It must be because the Solaris install is not using blas, but the numpy scripts are reporting that the libs are 'found'.

```
$python3 -c "import numpy.distutils.system_info as f; d = f.get_info('blas',0); print(d); d = f.get_info('lapack',0); print(d)"
 {'libraries': ['sunperf'], 'library_dirs': ['/home/$myname/local/archive/SolarisStudio12.2-solaris-sparc-tar-ML/solstudio12.2/lib'], 'language': 'f77'}
 {'libraries': ['sunmath'], 'library_dirs': ['/home/$myname/local/archive/SolarisStudio12.2-solaris-sparc-tar-ML/solstudio12.2/lib'],'language': 'f77'}
```

The following import FAILS on the Solaris install but succeeds on OSX:

import numpy.core._dotblas

There is no ATLAS available for the Solaris install. I wouldn't think this would make such a huge different in computational efficiency.

Any suggestions for other tests? Does the distutils.system_info not necessarily mean anything about the install? I tried the numpy.alterdot() command but that seems to have no effect.

Even more notes:

And I basically followed the setup on http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Solaris, except that my site.cfg looked like:

```
[DEFAULT]
library_dirs = $PATH_TO_MY_SOLARIS_DIR/SolarisStudio12.2-solaris-sparc-tar-ML/solstudio12.2/lib
[blas]
blas_libs = sunperf
[lapack]
lapack_libs = sunmath
```

Comment: Just noticed this comment in numpy/core/setup.py:

# dotblas needs ATLAS, Fortran compiled blas will not be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [mathtick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287238/mathtick) answer in the comments, the problem stems from the fact that `dotblas` needs `ATLAS`. Fortran-complied blas is not sufficient (per a comment in `numpy/core/setup.py`)

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139075/187647) for why I'm answering an old post.